# Resizing a canvas to the size of a pasted-in image when the pasted-in image is larger than the canvas

Tags: image-resizing, gimp

First, I know this is a terrible workflow; it's being enforced on me by my employer's SDL Tridion Docs content management system, which seems to specialize in showing complete contempt for its users.

I need to open a raster image in Gimp, paste in a new image, resize the canvas, save and close. This works fine when the pasted-in image is smaller than the original image, but when the pasted-in image is larger I cannot for the life of me find a function to detect the size of the pasted-in image and expand the canvas to fit; all of the functionality seems to assume that the new image will be smaller. I'm looking for the equivalent of the "resize document to selection" command found in Inkscape.

Answer (score 1):

If you do this manually, see Image>Fit canvas to layers.

If you do it in a script, `pdb.gimp_image_resize_to_layers(image)` in python, something similar in Script-fu.

Comment: Well, yes and no. Using a combination of Fit Canvas to Layer and To New Layer works. I was hoping to boil it down to one command. I've got a bunch of engineers who are already going to be unhappy about using SDL and I'm looking to make everything else as simple as possible.

Comment: @jrhooker You have to use "To new layer" (or Ctrl-Shift-N)  if you do a regular paste (`Edit>Paste` or Ctrl-V). But you can also do `Edit>Paste as>New layer` that creates a new layer directly without creating a floating selection (and you can assign it to a shortcut). There is also the solution to do Ctrl-V, Ctrl-Shift-N. And since this is is StackOverflow you can also write a short script that does everything (paste, new layer, resize canvas) in one operation, and assign it to a shortcut.